# Is there any way to enable AutoStart Permission for app without open its Screen in Android?

Tags: android

I want give permission of auto-start to my app in MIUI Devices without open its Screen.
We Can do by Open its Activity, and that's work perfectly but how can we do by Programmatically 
here is my code for open its activity

```
 try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
        if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
        } else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
        } else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
        } else if ("oneplus".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.oneplus.security", "com.oneplus.security.chainlaunch.view.ChainLaunchAppListAct‌​ivity"));
        }

        List<ResolveInfo> list = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error", "" + e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: No, you can't do that...Even Whatsapp not doing.

Comment: so, we cannot do this, and i think whats app is whitelisted already for enable it

Comment: Yes may be. But we can not do this automatically.

Comment: MIUI has whitelisted some of the major Apps that rely deeply on push notifications. You can ask the developers to do the same for your application even though the odds are against you or take the user directly to the App permission screen.

Comment: ok, thats sound nice